# Программное отключение USB устройств, проверка USB устройств на "занятость". С++

Tags: c++, linux, usb, libusb

Пишу небольшую программу для работы с USB С++, ОС Linux. Использую библиотеку libusb-1.0.
Задачи, которые я себе поставил.

- Вывод списка подключенных USB устройств.(Сделано)
- Обрабатывать события(вывод информации об устройстве) при подключении\отключении USB устройства.(Сделано).
- Обрабатывать события безопасного\небезопасного извлечения. (Не сделано)
- Возможность программного отключения USB устройств. (Не сделано)

Подскажите, как мне определить занято ли устройство операциями записи, чтения? (Относятся к устройствам хранения данных).

Как можно организовать программное отключение USB устройств?

Из того, что я нашёл:

- для отключения, можно использовать команду `libusb_control_transfer`, однако я не нашёл какой сигнал нужно отправить для отключения питания устройства. Ссылка на исходный код утилиты, которая должна решить это вопрос https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/blob/master/uhubctl.c но у меня она не заработала(я установил и попытался отключить питание от 1 порта, у меня там была флешка, но ничего не произошло).
- Для решения задачи, должна подходить библиотека `libudev`, однако я хотел бы решить все задачи используя `libusb-1.0`

Comment: питание не отключается на большинстве хостов. скорее надо флешке на языке флешки сказать чтоб она выключилась.